# How to implement licensing feature in web app using laravel 5.1+

Tags: laravel-5.1, licensing, license-key

I am working on laravel 5.1+ project which is divide in two part one is a centralized database management and another part will be for clients to manage their services. Centralized database application have the feature to manage client application. The centralized database application will have a list of clients with services offered and the validity of the services.

To manage the above process there should be licensing process and each client has to purchase the license and license must have the validity. There should be a manual and automatic validation of license.

If license expire then client can use only the basic feature of the application not more than that and if license will expire will a define period then a message should popup on client application.

Please friends, help me to implement this feature, is there any plugin available. If yes where to start or example to start on. If i need to do from scratch then let me know the flow.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no plugin available currently.**

But you can easily build your own to build a custom plugin module to check the license is valid.

If your customer is non-technical they can't break the license. But if they are programmers, they can easily break your license.

But at the same time, you can create your plugin with more hash keys and encryption methods to strengthen its code as much as you can.

Additional licensing software like ionCube works good with standard php. But I didn't check it with laravel like frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sribna/licensor - license server
https://github.com/sribna/licensee - client
This is for Lara 7.